# Messy JSON output of Google Sheet

Tags: json, google-sheets

I'm trying to use Google Sheets as a JSON backend. The JSON output is here:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/15Vn0lMn_lIq3P_QKcJ2Obs65FvqbMEoxSPuj9qrQH98/od6/public/values?alt=json

This is the published spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15Vn0lMn_lIq3P_QKcJ2Obs65FvqbMEoxSPuj9qrQH98/pubhtml

The problem is that the JSON output seems to be garbled. A sample line in the code is as follows:

```
 {"type":"text","$t":"day: Monday, menu: Paninis, baguettes, spaghetti / Chicken curry"}
```

I'm not getting the 'elegant and easily parse-able' JSON output.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you get that JSON URL from? Looks like you might be using some internal JSON format, not the actual [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

That's what the sheets output looks like using the url structure. You will want to look a little farther down to the gsx elements. That allows you to access the individual cell element rather than the combined elements.

You can get something more like this.

```
"gsx$day": {
"$t": "Tuesday"
},
"gsx$meal": {
"$t": "Lunch"
},
"gsx$menu": {
"$t": "Paninis, baguettes, spaghetti / Chicken curry"
}
```